# NSMutable Array: Getting "out of scope" Status After Mutable Copying

Tags: iphone, xcode, soap, nsmutablearray, sudzc

I have a `SOAP` service and I generated classes and functions on [SudzC.com](http://www.SudzC.com).

So I'm using the soap functions they generated, it returns an `NSMutableArray` with objects that are inherited by my custom class(which is generated by them, too).

So far everything's good. My values are getting into the array and I could see any property of any object with one condition: Only inside of the function that's handling the service.

Just to make it clear, here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    SDZGeneratedWebService* service = [SDZGeneratedWebService service];
    service.logging = YES;

    [service callMyData:self action:@selector(callMyDataHandler:) dataId: 1];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void) callMyDataHandler: (id) value {

    // Handle errors
    if([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", value);
        return;
    }

    // Handle faults
    if([value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", value);
        return;
    }               

    // Do something with the NSMutableArray* result
    NSMutableArray *result = (NSMutableArray *)value;
    MyCustomClass *myObject = [result objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@", myObject.myProperty); //Works Great
}
```

Like I said, so far everything's perfect. But I need to use the data outside of this function.

So in my `.h` file, I created an array like `NSMutableArray *myDataArray;`

When I intend to copy the `result` array to `myDataArray`, it copies the objects(I can see that the `myDataArray.count` value is equal to `result` array's) but all the objects are "`out of scope`". So I cannot use them.

I also tried to copy all objects by indexes in a `for loop`, nope, the objects are getting their values, but when I "`addObject`" to `myDataArray`, same, `out of scope`.

What is wrong here? Can't I generate an array of a custom class this way?

Edit: The code I'm generating myDataArray:

```
    myDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [myDataArray removeAllObjects];
    for (int i=0; i<((NSMutableArray *)result).count; i++) {
        MyCustomClass *myObject = [result objectAtIndex:i];
        [myDataArray addObject:myObject];
        [myObject release];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
} //(End of callMyDataHandler function)
```

I before tried this way, too:

```
    [myDataArray removeAllObjects];
    duyurular = [result mutableCopy];
} //(End of callMyDataHandler function)
```

Comment: Post code where you are creating both of this arrays - source and dst.

Comment: I suppose they appear "out of scope" in the debugger, right ? Have you tried to access them programatically ? Does it throw an exception ?

Comment: @EricMORAND, Right, I check them in the debugger but I also fill the table and labels come with text "Label". I'll check out again if I'm making it wrong.

Comment: `[myDataArray addObject:bizimBiArkadas];`??? Why not `[myDataArray addObject: myObject];`? And you don't need to release it = remove `[myObject release];`

Comment: @Nekto, No no, it is myObject, I just rename objects name when I paste here to make it more clear. It is myObject like I said, I assure you.

Comment: Check my answer about approach to copy arrays.

Comment: @EricMORAND was right, it was seeming "out of scope" while debugging, and I changed the function as initWithArray and arrays with NSArrays. So thank you both, both solutions worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy objects from one array to another using this method:

```
NSArray *source;
NSArray *dst = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:source];
```

In your code you should remove line: `[myObject release];` and I would better call `[((NSMutableArray *)result) count]` rather then using dot notation.

Comment: I actually used this way before, too. Anyway, I retried, I also changed NSMutableArrays to NSArrays, no, still the inner array is all right but myDataArray's objects are "out of scope".

Comment: Show how you are adding objects to `(NSMutableArray *)result`